# Cast different types into same trait object

Tags: rust, traits

I have a vector of different types represented as a vector of boxed trait objects. Depending on the type, I may have to do some preprocessing to its value before I can add it to my vector.

To do this, I created an enum where depending on the match arm I decide on whether the processing needs to happen or not. However, I noticed there is a lot of code duplication after I process my value. I need to wrap it into a different type and box it so I can add it to my vector.

I then tried to remove this code duplication by only processing the value in the match statement and then wrapping it and boxing it out of the match statement. The problem is that the code no longer compiles after that.

Is there any modification I can do to make the code compile?

Below is a simplified version of my code. `fun1` compiles just fine, but neither `fun2` nor `fun3` compile. I expect all functions to print the same message in `main`.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6dbe8e9c1f67dcaaa8cd117db0ad90ca)

```rust
pub trait Numeric {}

impl Numeric for i64 {}
impl Numeric for i32 {}
impl Numeric for i16 {}
impl Numeric for i8 {}
impl Numeric for u64 {}
impl Numeric for u32 {}
impl Numeric for u16 {}
impl Numeric for u8 {}
impl Numeric for usize {}
impl Numeric for isize {}

trait Quote {
    fn quote(&self) -> String;
}

impl Quote for &str {
    fn quote(&self) -> String {
        format!("'{}'", &self)
    }
}

impl<T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display> Quote for T {
    fn quote(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}", &self)
    }
}

fn process_numeric<T>(num: T) -> T
where
    T: Numeric,
{
    // Here we do some computation
    num
}

enum QuoteVariant<'a, T>
where
    T: Numeric,
{
    STR(&'a str),
    NUMERIC(T),
}

struct MyType<T> {
    pub id: usize,
    pub thing: T,
}

impl<T: Quote> Quote for MyType<T> {
    fn quote(&self) -> String {
        format!("ID: {} - thing: {}", self.id, self.thing.quote())
    }
}

fn fun1<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    // - The only purpose of the match statement is to decide whether
    // - there should be preprocessing or not to the type
    //
    // - Once this is determined we just add 'thing' into MyType and box it
    //
    // - The code below compiles but it creates a lot of repetition in the match's arms
    // - i.e. create MyType and box it
    match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => {
            // - Nothing to preprocess
            let mt = MyType { id: 0, thing: x };
            let bx = Box::new(mt) as Box<dyn Quote>;
            v.push(bx);
        }
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => {
            // - first we need to process our number
            let n = process_numeric(n);
            let mt = MyType { id: 0, thing: n };
            let bx = Box::new(mt) as Box<dyn Quote>;
            v.push(bx);
        }
    }
}

fn fun2<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    let mt: &'v dyn Quote;
    mt = match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => {
            let mt = MyType { id: 0, thing: x };
            &mt as &dyn Quote
        }
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => {
            // - first we need to process our number
            let n = process_numeric(n);
            let mt = MyType { id: 0, thing: n };
            &mt as &dyn Quote
        }
    };

    // - We box MyType after match statement
    let bx = Box::new(mt);
    v.push(bx);
}

fn fun3<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    let quote: &'v dyn Quote;
    quote = match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => &x as &'v dyn Quote,
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => {
            // - first we need to process our number
            let n = process_numeric(n);
            &n as &dyn Quote
        }
    };

    // - We create MyType after the match statement
    let mt = MyType {
        id: 0,
        thing: quote,
    };
    let bx = Box::new(mt);
    v.push(bx);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Quote>> = vec![];

    let q1: QuoteVariant<'_, usize> = QuoteVariant::STR("abcd");
    let q2 = QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(1);

    fun1(&mut v, q1);
    fun1(&mut v, q2);

    for value in &v {
        println!("{}", value.quote());
    }

    v.clear();

    let q1: QuoteVariant<'_, usize> = QuoteVariant::STR("abcd");
    let q2 = QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(1);

    fun2(&mut v, q1);
    fun2(&mut v, q2);

    for value in &v {
        println!("{}", value.quote());
    }

    v.clear();

    let q1: QuoteVariant<'_, usize> = QuoteVariant::STR("abcd");
    let q2 = QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(1);

    fun3(&mut v, q1);
    fun3(&mut v, q2);

    for value in &v {
        println!("{}", value.quote());
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly, this is not possible since, when you take the reference and cast it to dyn reference, wrapping it in box does not do what you think it should. You are trying to construct the trait object out of a trait object and since you did not add blanket impl for references, this does not work. What you want is impossible mainly because turning T to box of T may run different instructions then turning U to box of U. When you cast reference into dyn reference, you are loosing type information + reference is not owned and will not move the object

Comment: Unfortunately the strategies applied in your `fun2` and `fun3` are not applicable since you are trying to put some reference of an object to the outer vector, and the object is created in the function's scope, I removed the repetitive code from  `fun1`, you can use it like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=655facec60eb4207cabe6a03735ced97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any modification I can do to make the code compile?

In `fun2`, you have to move the `Box` inside the match arms: `MyType` is created in the match arms, so the arms are its owner, so at the end of the match arm `mt` is dropped and your references are dangling.

Because `v` constraints the output value, so you can leverage type inference in your casting, you don't need to faff about spelling out everything:

```rust
fn fun2<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    let bx = match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => Box::new(MyType { id: 0, thing: x }) as _,
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => {
            // - first we need to process our number
            let n = process_numeric(n);
            Box::new(MyType { id: 0, thing: n }) as _
        }
    };

    v.push(bx);
}
```

It's a bit of a simplified version of both fun1 and fun2 really.

`fun3` I think can't work, because the result of `process_numeric` is *at best* owned by `fun3`, so a reference to it can't escape the function, which makes pushing into the vector illegal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros for that:

```rust
fn fun4<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    macro_rules! make_and_push{
        ($arg_quote:expr) => {
            {
                let mt = MyType {
                    id: 0,
                    thing: $arg_quote,
                };
                let bx = Box::new(mt) as Box<dyn Quote>;
                v.push(bx)
            }
        };
    }
    match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => make_and_push!(x),
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => make_and_push!(process_numeric(n)),
    }
}
```

Another option is to move some code into quote trait:

```rust
trait Quote {
    fn quote(&self) -> String;
    
    fn box_into_my_type<'v>(&self)->Box<dyn Quote+'v> where Self: Copy + 'v {
        Box::new(
            MyType{
                id: 0,
                thing: *self,
            }
        )
    }
}

fn fun5<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + Copy + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    let boxed = match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => x.box_into_my_type(),
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => process_numeric(n).box_into_my_type(),
    };
    v.push(boxed);
}
```

And third option is to move common code into function (I put it inside of fun6)

```rust
fn fun6<'v, 'a, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, variant: QuoteVariant<'a, T>)
where
    T: Numeric + std::fmt::Display + 'v,
    'a: 'v,
{
    fn box_and_push<'v, T>(v: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Quote + 'v>>, q: T)
    where
        T: Quote + 'v,
    {
        v.push(Box::new(MyType { id: 0, thing: q }));
    }
    let boxed = match variant {
        QuoteVariant::STR(x) => box_and_push(v, x),
        QuoteVariant::NUMERIC(n) => box_and_push(v, process_numeric(n)),
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `fun6` is probably the one I would use